# Reverse sync CiviCRM groups to Drupal organic groups

Tags: groups

We have a client who would like to sync their CiviCRM groups to Drupal organic groups.

This is opposite to the CiviCRM Organic Groups module which syncs organic groups TO CiviCRM groups.

Their are some oldish posts on the CiviCRM forum but I can't see anything recent (e.g. http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,14212.0.html). Any help would be appreciated.

Oliver

Comment: Hi ollie - you presumably noticed that this comment seems to be me saying it 'can' work on existing code - http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,14212.msg107401.html#msg107401 

Did you see this older thread - i think i remember other discussions - oh like this one http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=22162.0

keen to hear how you go. having invested some funds in getting og_mailinglist rebuilt for D7 i have never had a chance to deploy it

Answer (score 2):

We use civicrm_entity module + rules to do things like that. This blog gives a recipe for relationship to OG.

There are a couple of general civicrm+rule blogs

http://www.jackrabbithanna.com/articles/simple-rule-example-using-civicrm-entity

http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/complex-civicrm-relationship-role-synchronisation-recipe

But neither are specifically to OG - I think there is one somewhere though - or else maybe an og rules feature - if I find it I'll paste it in

Comment: Thanks Eileen. The reason we want the sync to OG is so we can make use of this module https://www.drupal.org/project/og_mailinglist. The client would like have automated mailing list/Google group function tied to their CviCRM groups and using that module and OG would seem to be a great solution.