# Way to sync CiviCRM memberships to Drupal group

Tags: drupal, civimember, groups, roles

The organization I work for wants to create a subscription that provides access to certain parts of our Drupal site using the CiviCRM membership subscription process, wherein they would subscribe to become a member of one of the memberships (there would be a couple dozen of such memberships and special access sections, one per membership type). I haven't figured out a good way to limit access to those parts of the site in Drupal and want to see if groups will do the trick. I am wondering if there is a way to sync memberships in CiviCRM with organic groups in Drupal?

Drupal 7.56 CiviCRM 4.7.27

Answer (score 1):

This question gives an answer to a very similar question that you can apply to your situation: [Reverse sync CiviCRM groups to Drupal organic groups](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/reverse-sync-civicrm-groups-to-drupal-organic-groups)

However, even with a couple dozen membership types, I still think it might be better to use regular CiviMember-Role sync and use a "limit content access by role" module.  I think [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) is the popular one.

Try both approaches and see what works for you!

Comment: My original approach was to use CiviMember Role Sync, which we're already using on the site and create a role for each access area, but there are potentially dozens of roles. Someone on the Drupal side suggested I try using groups. I will check out your suggestion, and I assume it will work for syncing memberships instead of CiviGroups? Thank you.

Comment: It should!  civicrm_entity should support Memberships, so use that plus Drupal Rules module so that when a membership is created, you grant access to an Organic Group.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the suggestions. I wanted to go ahead and post my solution. We ended up installing organic groups and then using the [CiviCRM OG Sync module](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+vs.+Organic+G%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20roups) to sync the [Drupal organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) to CiviCRM groups. The key here is that users sign up on the Drupal end *first* and then get synced to the CiviCRM back end.

The membership types ended up needing a lot of CMS type functionality, rather than CiviCRM membership functionality, so this worked out for us.

Comment: Good plan. FYI we have made further use of these types of features, eg synching to an OG based on Relationship, or on Event Participation in case either of those sound useful to you